# How do I color a fontawesome icon with javascript?

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I have the following `fa-icon`:

```
<div id="notification">
    <div id="info">
        <div class="service">
            <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
            <h1 class="name"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following to color it with javascript:

```
var Music = (swatches.DarkVibrant.getHex());
document.getElementById("info").getElementsByClassName("service")[0].style.color = Music;

// Gave i element this id
document.querySelector('#music').style.color = Music;
document.querySelector('.fas fa-music').style.color = Music;
```

However none of them work, how could I achieve this?

Edit: it seems like it only works outside my function, why does it not work when its inside?

```
// Works
document.querySelector('.fas').style.color = "blue"

function mainUpdate(type) {
    if (type == "music") {
        if (isplaying) {
            document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML = "Now playing";
            document.querySelector('.details').innerHTML = "• " + album;
            document.querySelector('.song').innerHTML = title;
            document.querySelector('.artist').innerHTML = artist;
            var milli = new Date().getMilliseconds();
            var albumart = document.querySelector("#artworkImage");
            albumart.src = "/var/mobile/Documents/Artwork.jpg?" + milli;
            albumart.addEventListener('load', function () {
                var vibrant = new Vibrant(albumart);
                var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
                for (var swatch in swatches)
                    if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch]) {
                        var Name = (swatches.DarkVibrant.getHex());
                        var Music = (swatches.DarkVibrant.getHex());
                    }
                document.querySelector('.name').style.color = Name; // Works
                document.querySelector('.fas').style.color = "blue" // Doesnt work
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of FontAwesome are you using

Comment: https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css

Comment: try running the javascript on the `fa-music` class

Comment: I just tried that, it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Since 5.0 uses SVG try

```
document.querySelector('.fas fa-music').style.fill = Music;
```

If this does not work then you will have to select SVG inside and apply rule in it

Comment: It did not work for me, could you explain how I can select SVG and apply the rule?

Comment: Basically you will have to do something like this document.querySelector(“div > svg”).style.fill = “your color”

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
document.querySelector('.fa.fa-sign-in').style.color = "green"
```

You have a mistake in your selector. For your case, the correct line to modify the styles will be

```
document.querySelector('.fas.fa-music').style.color = "green"
```

Change "green" to your color

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following code?

```
document.querySelector('#info .service .fa-music').style.color = Music;
```

This one should also work:

```
document.querySelector('.fas.fa-music').style.color = Music;
```

It seems that you made a small mistake by writing `('.fas fa-music')`.

Comment: @Daniell Are you sure that your JS file is connected correctly to the HTML file? Trying a simple alert() function will show if it's connected correctly. Also, if you put the code in Codepen or Pastebin, it would be a bit easier to check what's wrong

Comment: Yes because it does color text elements with javascript, in the dev tools I can also change the color with css but it just does not apply the color with javascript, could anyone test if it works for them?